# Mi php comprueba mal el usuario

Tags: php, jquery, base-de-datos

Tengo un formulario para intentar hacer un signup en php:

```
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="nick">Nick</label>
        <input type="text" name="nickname" class="nick" required maxlength="50">
        <span id="result"></span>
        <input class="form-btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Suscribe"/>
    </form>
```

Con el siguiente script para comprobar mediante el keyup si el nombre que se elige está disponible:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){    
        $(".nick").keyup(function(){  
            let nick = $(this).val(); 
            if(nick.length > 5){  
                $("#result").html('checking...');
                $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url  : 'usernamecheck.php',
                data : $(this).serialize(),
                success : function(data){
                    $("#result").html(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
            } else {
                $("#result").html('');
            }
        });
    });
```

Todo esto se envía con POST al siguiente archivo:

```
<?php
  
  $host="localhost";
  $user="root";
  $pass="";
  $dbname="test-users";
  
  $dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname}",$user,$pass);
  
  if($_POST) 
  {
    $nick = strip_tags($_POST['nick']);
      
   $stmt=$dbcon->prepare("SELECT nick FROM user WHERE nick=:nick");
   $stmt->execute(array(':nick'=>$nick));
   $count=$stmt->rowCount();
      
   if($count>0)
   {
    echo "<span style='color:brown;'>Sorry username already taken !!!</span>";
   }
   else
   {
    echo "<span style='color:green;'>available</span>";
   }
  }
?>
```

Pero siempre que pongo el nombre de usuario Aaron, me dice que está disponible, y en la base de datos tengo registrado a Aaron con id 1.

¿En qué estoy fallando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `name` del `input` es `nickname`, por lo que en `PHP` la variable que vas a recibir es `$_POST['nickname']`.

Como `$_POST['nick']` no existe, siempre estas buscando el `user` cuyo `nick` es igual a vacío y evidentemente no existe ninguno.

#### Solución:

Podrías simplemente cambiar el `name` del `input` a `"nick"`

```
<input type="text" name="nick" class="nick" required maxlength="50">
```

---

**Comentario:** En desarrollo suele ser útil activar [la notificación de errores de `NOTICE`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) y así detectar rápidamente este tipo de errores.

> La habilitación de `E_NOTICE` durante el desarrollo tiene algunos beneficios. Para las depuración: los mensajes `NOTICE` avisarán de posibles errores en el código. Por ejemplo, se advierte del uso de valores no asignados. **Es extremadamente útil para encontrar errartas y ahorrar tiempo en la depuración.**[...]

```
// Por ejemplo, activar el reporte de todos los errores
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: QUE LÁSTIMA QUE SOLO PUEDA DARTE UN VOTO!!!! Llevaba HORAS atascado!

Comment: Para ese tipo de cosas, existen las recompensas... @AQMR